# Default variables in virtual functions

Tags: c++

I'm sure there is already a proper answer for this question on StackOverflow but I didn't manage to find it.

I met this example at some c++ test and it was an unexpected behaviour for me.

```
class A {
public:
    virtual int foo(int n = 3) {
        return n << 2;
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    int foo(int n = 4) {
        return n << 3;
    }
};

void main() {
    B b;
    A *a = &b;
    std::cout << a->foo() << std::endl;
}
```

I always knew that overwritten **foo** from **B** class would be called in example, but default value for **n** taken from **base** class **foo** was really unexpected.

The same output (24) we'll obtain by replacing **pointer** to B with **reference** to B.

**My questions are**:

- Why is **n** initialized with **3** instead of **4**?
- Could someone provide some explanation (if it possible, with some **specification** references) for that behaviour?

Comment: Changing the default variable on a virtual function is a really bad idea in general. Please don't do that. (I think there might even be an entry in one of Scott Meyer's books about this?)

Comment: I never intended to do so=) It was a simple test and I was sure about the answer=)